# How to connect to websocket private channel using rxjs

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

Hello I want to connect to a private websocket channel using rxjs can anyone point me to the right direction, documentation or tutorial

I was able to connect to the websocket successfully but now I want to subscribe to a private channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Pusher not Rxjs

```
this.pusher = new Pusher(environment.pusherKey, {
  wsHost: environment.pusherHost,
  wsPort: port,
  wssPort: port,
  forceTLS: true,
  disableStats: true,
  enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
  authEndpoint: `${apiUrl}/auth/pusher`,
  auth: {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${
        this.authService.getAuthFromLocalStorage().authToken
      }`,
    },
  },
});
```

ofcourse I had to authenticate in my backend service with is laravel by the following method

```
public function pusherAuth(Request $request){
    $user = auth()->user();
    $socket_id = $request['socket_id'];
    $channel_name =$request['channel_name'];
    $key = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.key');
    $secret = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.secret');
    $app_id = config('broadcasting.connections.pusher.app_id');

    if ($user) {
        $authData = json_encode([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'user_info' => [
                'name' => $user->name
            ]
        ]);
        $pusher = new Pusher($key, $secret, $app_id);
        $auth = $pusher->socket_Auth($channel_name, $socket_id,$authData);

        return response($auth, 200);

    }
    return new Response('Unauthorized', 401);
}
```

Note that I used a php debuger which changed the default auth response that gave me that error

[Error: JSON returned from channel-authorization endpoint was invalid, yet status code was 200.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEY4u.png)

To solve it either we close debugging from .env or from the debugbar config "except option"